# PhoneGap upload photos: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, cordova

I'm trying to create an application that will upload a photo to a mongodb server, here is my code:

```
   upload = function (imageURI) {
        var ft = new FileTransfer(),
            options = new FileUploadOptions();

        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = 'filename.jpg'; Node at the server side.
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
        options.chunkedMode = false;
        options.params = { 
            "description": "Uploaded from my phone"
        };

        // alert(imageURI);
        // alert(serverURL);

        ft.upload(imageURI, serverURL + "/images",
            function (e) {
                getFeed();
            },
            function (e) {
                alert("Upload failed");
            }, options);
    }
```

and on the node server side this is where the error seems to happen:

```
    exports.addImage = function(req, res, next) {
    var file = req.files.file,
        filePath = file.path,
        lastIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf("/"),
        tmpFileName = filePath.substr(lastIndex + 1),
        image = req.body,
        images = db.collection('images');

    image.fileName = tmpFileName;
    console.log(tmpFileName);

    images.insert(image, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return next(err);
        }
        res.json(image);
    });

};
```

so I'm having the error Cannot read property 'file' of undefined

Comment: what is "Node at the server side." ?

Comment: just added server side code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is an error related to the version of the express that you are using. In previous version of express (3.x) you should include :

`app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.multipart());`

so you can access to req.files